# SuspiciousFileOperation at /file/upload/ Detected path traversal attempt in '/app/media/Resume/Lal.pdf'

Tags: django, heroku, django-rest-framework, dropbox, django-storage

I am trying to upload a file to dropbox using django restframework. I am running the app on heroku. I am getting the following error :

```
SuspiciousFileOperation at /file/upload/
Detected path traversal attempt in '/app/media/Resume/Lal.pdf'
```

I have deployed the app on heroku as I am getting below path issue in my local machine

```
ValidationError at /file/upload/
'C:/Apisero/practice/Django_Projects/fileuploadpocusingparser/media/Resume/Lal.pdf' did not match pattern '(/(.|[\r\n])*|id:.*)|(rev:[0-9a-f]{9,})|(ns:[0-9]+(/.*)?)'
```

This is first time I am using dropbox with django and I have tried my best to find the issue but I couldn't. TIA.
Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/file_app/views.py", line 14, in post
    file_serializer.save()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 212, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 962, in create
    instance = ModelClass._default_manager.create(**validated_data)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 453, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 739, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 776, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 881, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 919, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1270, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1415, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1358, in as_sql
    value_rows = [
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1359, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1359, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1310, in pre_save_val
    return field.pre_save(obj, add=True)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 302, in pre_save
    file.save(file.name, file.file, save=False)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 89, in save
    self.name = self.storage.save(name, content, max_length=self.field.max_length)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 56, in save
    validate_file_name(name, allow_relative_path=True)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/files/utils.py", line 18, in validate_file_name
    raise SuspiciousFileOperation(

Exception Type: SuspiciousFileOperation at /file/upload/
Exception Value: Detected path traversal attempt in '/app/media/Resume/Lal_Jan_Basha_Resume.pdf-4-1_d8crH6p.pdf'
```

These are all the files:

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.dropbox.DropBoxStorage'


DROPBOX_OAUTH2_TOKEN = 'xxxxxxxxx'
DROPBOX_ROOT_PATH = 'media/'
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class File(models.Model):
  file = models.FileField(upload_to='Resume')
```

serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import File

class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta():
    model = File
    fields = '__all__'
```

views.py :

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser, FormParser
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from .serializers import FileSerializer

class FileView(APIView):
  parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)

  def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # return Response('Hello')
    file_serializer = FileSerializer(data=request.data)
    if file_serializer.is_valid():
      file_serializer.save()
      return Response(file_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
      return Response(file_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Hi, did you happen to solve this issue somehow?